# Change gtk Calendar locale on the fly

Tags: c++, calendar, gtk, location, set

I've a GTK Calendar in my C++ GTK application, and I have a button to switch the language between English and Arabic.

When I change the language on the fly, I change the locale with *setlocale* and then I set the text of all the GTK components with *gtk_X_set_text()* functions, getting the string associated to the new locale.  But I don't know how can I change the calendar location on the fly. I only can see the calendar in other location if a change the location of the system before executing the app.

Thank you.